# What do element, event, ui variables mean? - jQuery (UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For example: (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    deactivate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

A lot of jQuery API descriptions of functions have these kind of parameters.
They come in lots of formats: el, element, elem, ev, event, ui etc.
Can someone explain to me how to interpret this? I tested the above function and it does not seem to require any of this input?

Comment: The description of the method has details about both arguments.

Comment: It's explained in the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-deactivate

Comment: `event` is a jQuery event object (`deactivate` is a custom event).  `ui` is an object containing various properties.

Comment: *You* are not passing anything to this function, it's callback (an event).  Those values are passed by jQuery to the function, they are there if you need them.

Comment: Thank you all for your reactions. I am having difficulties reading the jQuery descriptions. Sadly the website has no instructions on how to read it, or does it?

Answer (score 1):

They are parameters. You can name them whatever you want:

```
function myFunc(a){
    alert(a);
}

myFunc("Hello");
```

Is the same as:

```
function myFunc(whatever){
    alert(whatever);
}

myFunc("Hello");
```

Also, because javascript is not strongly typed, you are not required to invoke a function with the correct number of parameters:

```
function fourArgs(a, b, c, d){
}

function oneArg(a){
}

fourArg("Hello"); // a will be the string 'Hello', b c and d will be undefined

oneArg("Hello", 1, 2, 3); // a will be the string 'Hello', the other values are not referenced (they can still be accessed through arguments)
```

So, you create a function and passes it to jQuery to use it as callback. jQuery will always invoke it with the arguments specified in the docs. Whether you will name the arguments to use in the function you created, is up to you. You can omit it if you do not intend to use them.